# Xcode 13 crashes unexpectedly on opening xcworkspace of my Obj-C project

Tags: objective-c, ios15, xcode13

I Had to update my app to IOS15 and to do that I had to test the code on ios15 simulator, I was on xcode 12.5 and MAC OS 11.2 (Big SUR) , So in order to update the Xcode to xcode13 I had to first update the Mac OS to 11.3 or later. So I updated the Mac OS followed by updating the Xcode 12.5 to Xcode 13. But now whenever I open my project it crashes unexpectedly.

Following solutions have been tried:

1. Writing main thread command on terminal
2. Deleting derived data
3. Deleting xcuserdata inside the xcworkspace content
4. Restarting mac multiple times
5. deleted whole xcode folder from ~Library/ folder
6. Deleted cache

Below is the terminal logs when opening xcode which end up in abort.

> 2021-09-24 21:09:32.367 Xcode[820:16763] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning
> in
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-19207/DVTUserInterfaceKit/CustomUI/DVTScrollView.m:126
> Details:  Mutating -contentInsets may produce unexpected results when
> borders are drawn. Use -contentInsetsExcludingBorders instead. Object:
> <DVTScrollView_ControlledBy_PreviewsXcode.AttributesInspectorViewController:
> 0x7fe99ba83800> Method:   -setContentInsets: Thread:   <NSThread:
> 0x7fe9bad1da80>{number = 1, name = main} Please file a bug at
> https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any
> useful information you can provide. 2021-09-24 21:09:32.492
> Xcode[820:16763] Looking for Simulator.app in (
> "DVTFilePath:0x7fe96c66ce50:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications'"
> ) 2021-09-24 21:10:50.650 Xcode[820:19185]  DVTAssertions: Warning in
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-19234/IDEFoundation/Execution/LaunchSystem/IDELaunchSession.m:1392
> Details:  XPC Debugging registration timedout -- continuing Object:
> <IDELaunchSession: 0x7fe98a22fac0> Method:
> -_startObservingXPCServicesAndAppExtensionsStage2 Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe99c1acce0>{number = 48, name = (null)} Please file a bug at
> https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any
> useful information you can provide. 2021-09-24 21:12:19.863
> Xcode[820:16763] -[__NSCFBoolean mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized
> selector sent to instance 0x7fff8070c230 2021-09-24 21:12:19.866
> Xcode[820:16763] [MT] DVTAssertions: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
> (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFBoolean mutableCopyWithZone:]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8070c230 UserInfo: (null)
> Open FDs: 84/7168 Hints:  2021-09-24 21:12:20.200 Xcode[820:16763]
> [MT] DVTAssertions:  Backtrace:   0   __exceptionPreprocess (in
> CoreFoundation)   1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in
> DVTFoundation)   2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)   3
> -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] (in CoreFoundation)   4   ***forwarding*** (in CoreFoundation)   5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)   6   -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel
> readValuesFromPlist] (in Xcode3Core)   7
> -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel initWithCapabilitiesContext:item:] (in Xcode3Core)   8
> -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext capabilityItemModels] (in DevToolsCore)   9   -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext
> _appIDFeatureStateForEntitlements:expansion:] (in DevToolsCore)  10   -[Xcode3Target appIDFeaturesForBuildParameters:entitlements:withEntitlementsExpansion:]
> (in DevToolsCore)  11   -[Xcode3Target
> _profileSupportForSDK:configuration:scope:] (in DevToolsCore)  12   -[Xcode3Target profileSupportForBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)  13   +[IDEProvisionableSnapshot
> snapshotFromProvisionable:buildParameters:overrides:] (in
> IDEFoundation)  14   __62-[IDEProvisionableManager
> _evaluateStatusWithStatusEvaluator:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)  15
> ___DVTCachedTimeSlicedMainThreadBlockProcessingQueueForKey_block_invoke_2
> (in DVTFoundation)  16
> -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadOrderedNonUniquingWorkQueue _processWorkItemsWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)  17   -[DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadWorkQueue _processWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)  18   -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadActiveWorkQueues
> _processWorkQueuesOnDeadline] (in DVTFoundation)  19   __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)  20   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** (in CoreFoundation)  21   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)  22
> __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)  23   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)  24   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)  25
> RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)  26   ReceiveNextEventCommon
> (in HIToolbox)  27   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
> (in HIToolbox)  28   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)  29
> -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)  30   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)  31   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  32   -[DVTApplication
> run] (in DVTKit)  33   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  34   start (in
> libdyld.dylib) Abort trap: 6 logout Saving session... ...copying
> shared history... ...saving history...truncating history files...
> ...completed.
>
> [Process completed]

And the code quit unexpectedly Crash error report is below:

> > Process:               Xcode [820] Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
> > com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               13.0 (19234) Build Info:
> > IDEFrameworks-19234000000000000~16 (13A233) App Item ID:
> > 497799835 App External ID:       844005016 Code Type:
> > X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        bash [814] Responsible:
> > Terminal [801] User ID:               505
>
> Date/Time:             2021-09-24 21:12:20.265 +1000 OS Version:
> macOS 11.6 (20G165) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:
> 436B3CE5-2698-C19C-324B-969964522643
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 470 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: disabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 13A233 UNCAUGHT
> EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSCFBoolean
> mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x7fff8070c230 UserInfo: (null) Open FDs: 84/7168 Hints:    Backtrace:
> 0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)   1
> DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)   2
> objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)   3   -[NSObject(NSObject)
> __retain_OA] (in CoreFoundation)   4   ***forwarding*** (in CoreFoundation)   5   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 (in CoreFoundation)   6
> -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel readValuesFromPlist] (in Xcode3Core)   7   -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel
> initWithCapabilitiesContext:item:] (in Xcode3Core)   8
> -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext capabilityItemModels] (in DevToolsCore)   9   -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext
> _appIDFeatureStateForEntitlements:expansion:] (in DevToolsCore)  10   -[Xcode3Target appIDFeaturesForBuildParameters:entitlements:withEntitlementsExpansion:]
> (in DevToolsCore)  11   -[Xcode3Target
> _profileSupportForSDK:configuration:scope:] (in DevToolsCore)  12   -[Xcode3Target profileSupportForBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore)  13   +[IDEProvisionableSnapshot
> snapshotFromProvisionable:buildParameters:overrides:] (in
> IDEFoundation)  14   __62-[IDEProvisionableManager
> _evaluateStatusWithStatusEvaluator:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)  15
> ___DVTCachedTimeSlicedMainThreadBlockProcessingQueueForKey_block_invoke_2
> (in DVTFoundation)  16
> -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadOrderedNonUniquingWorkQueue _processWorkItemsWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)  17   -[DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadWorkQueue _processWithDeadline:] (in DVTFoundation)  18   -[_DVTTimeSlicedMainThreadActiveWorkQueues
> _processWorkQueuesOnDeadline] (in DVTFoundation)  19   __NSFireDelayedPerform (in Foundation)  20   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** (in CoreFoundation)  21   __CFRunLoopDoTimer (in CoreFoundation)  22
> __CFRunLoopDoTimers (in CoreFoundation)  23   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)  24   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)  25
> RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)  26   ReceiveNextEventCommon
> (in HIToolbox)  27   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
> (in HIToolbox)  28   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)  29
> -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)  30   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)  31   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)  32   -[DVTApplication
> run] (in DVTKit)  33   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)  34   start (in
> libdyld.dylib)   abort() called
>
> Application Specific Signatures: NSInvalidArgumentException
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff205421db __exceptionPreprocess + 242 1   DVTFoundation
> 0x00000001071e200d DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor + 446 2
> libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff2027bd92
> objc_exception_throw + 48 3   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff205c4d0d -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0 4
> CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204aa24b
> ***forwarding*** + 1448 5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff204a9c18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120 6   Xcode3Core
> 0x000000012163bba4 -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel
> readValuesFromPlist] + 253 7   Xcode3Core
> 0x000000012163ba8e -[Xcode3AppTransportSecurityItemModel
> initWithCapabilitiesContext:item:] + 72 8   DevToolsCore
> 0x00000001218ed2c1 -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext
> capabilityItemModels] + 505 9   DevToolsCore
> 0x00000001218ed5ab -[Xcode3TargetCapabilitiesContext
> _appIDFeatureStateForEntitlements:expansion:] + 251 10  DevToolsCore                        0x00000001219970b4 -[Xcode3Target

I am totally stuck, please help!

Comment: doesnt the report say "XPC Debugging registration timedout". You may figure out why an update triggers such. It does not point on a timer timeout, it means a registration is not working. Meaning this report indicates there are problems with XPC service. As App and Xcode communicate this way to make debugging possible it can crash Xcode of course if a connection is never successful

Comment: These are the terminal logs, should i paste the code crash error report? I think it would help. Check the edit

Comment: what is suspicious in report above is "-[__NSCFBoolean mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8070c230 ", of course any proper crash report can help. Let's calm down first, at least it still reports.

Comment: If Xcode crashes, file a bug report with Apple. There's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: But he can still try to force Xcodes preferences to reset. If that works you know former settings backfire.. Maybe you run in the same problem but those `com.apple.dt.xyz..`files in your `/users/username/Library/Preferences/` folder can be erased which lets the app assume it is a fresh install on start. Be aware Xcode will forget your dev account and so on if you try that.. If that doesnt work out, indeed only bug reporting to Apple makes sense

Comment: deleted com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist in Library/preferences restarted Xcode, same file recreated and xcode crashes

Comment: @SaadurRehman you got any solution on this?

Comment: @Vijay HAd to fallback to xcode 12.5.1, no way out with xcode13

Comment: @SaadurRehman but cant support to iOS 15 with that xcode na?

Comment: @Vijay you would not be able to test on ios15 simulator, keep the deployment target lower and create the ipa, there are no breaking changes in ios15 so the app running on 14.5 will work equally well on IOS 15